# Changing code to send argument to API - Bash - Pastebin

Tags: curl, api

I've recently tried to use the following code to send paste to pastebin.com:

https://github.com/mefuckin/pastebin-shell/blob/master/pbin

What I've noticed with that script is that it doesn't appear to send api_user_key. Line 183 has it listed:

```
--data "api_user_key=$api_user_key" \
```

so I though it would just be a matter of specifying its value, as:

```
api_user_key="VALUE HERE"
```

and that would send it to the API. However, I'm unsure of what that part of the code does (part of code that starts at 174):

```
[ $logintopastebin -ne 0 ] && auth_user
api_paste_code=$( cat - )
curl -0 --show-error \
    --data "api_dev_key=$api_dev_key" \
    --data "api_option=paste" \
    --data "api_paste_code=$api_paste_code" \
    --data "api_paste_format=$api_paste_format" \
    --data "api_paste_private=$api_paste_private" \
    --data "api_paste_expire_date=$api_paste_expire_date" \
    --data "api_user_key=$api_user_key" \
    --data-urlencode "api_paste_name=$api_paste_name" \
    --data-urlencode "api_paste_code=$api_paste_code" \
        "$api_url/api_post.php"
```

Does this portion of the code mean that all these arguments will be sent to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does send the `api_user_key`. It may send an empty string if the variable is not set. The [script](https://github.com/mefuckin/pastebin-shell/blob/master/pbin) contains code to find the user key by querying the server in the function `auth_user`, but that function is only called if you set `logintopastebin` to a nonzero value at the beginning or if you pass one of the options `-u` or `-l` on the command line. You can override the value by setting the variable `api_user_key` manually after or instead of the call to `auth_user`, before the call to `curl`, e.g.

```
api_user_key=$(cat ~/.passwords/pastebin/api_user_key)
…
if [ -z "$api_user_key" ] && [ "$logintopastebin" -eq 0 ]; then
  auth_user
fi
api_paste_code=$( cat - )
curl -0 --show-error \
    …
```

If you don't understand what the script is doing, add `set -x` as the second line to make it print a trace of each line as it gets executed.

Comment: Thank you! It appears that even though I am setting api_user_key and even though I'm setting both -u and -l, the API still isn't recognising it, as it doesn't allow me to perform the requests that are tied to the api_user_key. 

Maybe that's something for pastebin.com ... :/

Comment: Disregard my last comment. Using the code you supplied and setting up api_user_key definitely worked and the "privileges" that are given via it were applied. Thank you.